# Was Media-Query ever part of CSS2?

Tags: html, css

I got a simple question - Were Media_Queries present in CSS2 (launched Nov 1997) or it came only in CSS 3(7 June 2011)?

> Media queries is a feature of CSS3 allowing content rendering to adapt
> to different conditions such as screen resolution (e.g. mobile and
> desktop screen size). It became a W3C recommended standard in June
> 2012,[1] and is a cornerstone technology of responsive web design
> (RWD).

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries

> CSS2 Introduced Media Types

> CSS3 Introduced Media Queries

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Now, I am pretty confused. Was *Media Query* a part of CSS2 or NOT? Was it already there or only *improved* in CSS3 or otherwise? Did it only came as a new feature in CSS3 or Whatever???

Comment: There's an obvious difference between Types and Queries!

Comment: Firstly, don't use Wikipedia or W3Schools as definitive sources :) Go straight to the source [W3.org CSS3 Media Queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). Also: take a look at the Wikipedia info you included, it says "*CSS2 Introduced Media **Types***"... media types are not the same as media queries - the Wikipedia link you include has a description of both, including a list of [media types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries#Media_types) so you can see the difference.

Comment: @FluffyKitten - but without media-queries what will we do only with 'media types'? Does it got any sense??? We use 'media-types' to write media-Query. Pls clarify.

Comment: @Paulie_D: as I asked above can you answer -- We use 'Media_types' to write Media_Queries - so if Media_Queries were not in CSS2, then weren't 'media_types' just redundant?

Comment: Media types are used for more than media queries! Did you read the info in the link to Wikipedia? "A media type can be declared in the head of an HTML document using the "media" attribute inside of a <link> element.The value of the "media" attribute specifies on what device the linked document will be displayed." e.g. braille, print, speech.

Comment: @FluffyKitten - Just for conclusion - so "Media Queries" came in 2012 only and were not available or in use till 2011, correct ???

Comment: All I can tell you is in the official W3C documentation that I linked to above, that it became a W3C Recommendation on 19 June 2012.

Answer (score 3):

CSS2 introduced only [Media Types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/media.html#q7.0) and the media query was defined later.

The first draft was written in [4 April 2001](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-mediaqueries-20010404/) and become a W3C recomendation in [19 June 2012](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). If you check the last link you can navigate to the previous versions to see the evolution of the Specification from 2001 to 2012.

Worth to note that browsers may have started the implementation earlier so the media query feature was available before June 2012.

If we consider caniuse: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_at-rules_media_width we can find a support for media query since 2006.

---

The above is only the Level 3 and actually we are at the Level 4 with this Specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/ which is a Candidate Recommendation and is mostly implemented by major browsers.

You can follow this link to see the changes from the Level 3 to the Level 4: https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#changes-2012

There is also a [Level 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-5/) that is under constrution and still in Draft mode. The date of the last version is 31 July 2020 and the first one was in [3 March 2020](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/WD-mediaqueries-5-20200303/). This one is still recent to talk about implementation.

---

It can be a bit confusing to follow all this but here is a link that explain the process done by the working group: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#w3c-process

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, CSS2 introduced simple @media types. For example, one for screen, one for print, etc.

For example:

```css
@media screen {
    /* screen only */
}
@media print {
    /* print only */
}
```

CSS3 introduced more complex @media queries. For example, the width of the device, or reduced motion, or colour schemes.

```css
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    /* viewports under 700px only */
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduced) {
    /* for motion-reduced browser settings */
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    /* for dark preferences on browser settings */
}
```

You can mix them both together.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    /* viewports over 1000px only, on screens */
}
@media print and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* for printing in portrait mode */
}
@media (max-device-width: 700px) and (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    /* for light preferences on browser settings on devices under 700px wide */
}
@media print and (min-device-width: 900px) and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduced) {
    /* for print, on devices over 900px wide, for reduced motion preferences on the browser settings */
}
```

**TL;DR:** CSS2 lets you do things for types of media, but CSS3 lets you do things for different preferences/settings/sizes in those media.

Comment: This pretty much hits the nail on the head, though I'd like to say, in line with the wording of the original question, you could say that a Media **Query** is an extension/improvement over Media **Types**; in that they let you narrow down your target even more.  **Media queries were part of CSS3, period.**  Their usage overlaps & bolsters media types that were part of CSS2.  You can see how media types and queries are used separately and together..